# SQL - get last month data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been using this query to extract information from last month

```
SELECT * 
FROM Member
WHERE DATEPART(m, date_created) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

with the end of the year approaching, will this automatically pull Dec 2012 when i run it in Jan 2013 ?

Comment: What is DatePart and is m = Month?

Comment: Judging by `DatePart`, I'd assume SQL Server.

Comment: You could simply check it by yourself with:
select DATEADD(mm, -1, '01-01-2013')

Comment: sorry still new to all of this. it is SQL Server.

Comment: thanks @MUDALOV. it checks correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. your getdate() function will give the current date when the query is run. And you are adding -1 to the month and comparing month of date_created column and the last month. But I think you should also do comparison of year. You should add two conditions month and year both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will pull December data. **But** it will pull December data from any year, not just 2012

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. DATEADD is a SQL internal function that adds to the full date, not just the selected part (day, month, year).